# How to make multiple connection from the source endpoint in jsplumb

Tags: jsplumb

I am trying to make a flowchart using jsplumb library. I need make multiple connections from a single div. Ex- Div 1 should connect to Div 2 and Div 3. I want the source endpoint to be the same i.e bottomcenter. Please let me know what should be done to make this work
Thanks!

Comment: I got the answer for this. Here it is, while creating the end points, you can set the 
                maxConnections:-1, 

for unlimited connections. If you set to some value, then it can make only the number of connections equals to value. You need to specify this in sourceEndpoint and targetEndpoint creation time

Comment: This solution didn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: @user1667230: Did you tried it to make the maxConnections=-1 to both the endpoints? If not then try that.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with addEndpoints, makeSource, and makeTarget. None of which worked. I can create one connection, no problem but after that, the endpoints seems full. I also tried upgrading the z-index of the endpoint. No luck.

Comment: It turned out that "deleteEndpointsOnDetach: false" broke the ability to create more than one connection without a massive refresh. Removing this parameter resolved the problem.

Comment: @user1667230: The z-index has nothing to do with it... Thanks for sharing your solution as well...

Answer (score 3):

For Target End Points set it global to make unlimited connections:

```
  var targetEndpoint = {
endpoint: "Dot",
paintStyle: { fillStyle: "blue", radius: 7 },
hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
maxConnections: -1,
dropOptions: { hoverClass: "hover", activeClass: "active" },
isTarget: true,
overlays: [["Label", { location: [0.5, -0.5], label: "", cssClass: "endpointTargetLabel" }]]
};
```

for source Endpoint set it global to make unlimited connections:

```
var sourceEndpoint = {
endpoint: "Dot",
paintStyle: {
    strokeStyle: "green", fillStyle: "green", radius: 3, lineWidth: 1
},
isSource: true,
maxConnections: -1,
connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], gap: 10, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
connectorStyle: connectorPaintStyle, hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle, connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
dragOptions: {},
overlays: [["Label", { location: [0.5, 1.5], label: "", cssClass: "endpointSourceLabel", }]]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to connect div1 to div2 and div3

```
<html>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/JsPlumb/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".inner").draggable({

                containment : ([ ".outer" ]),

            });

        var source = $("#div1");
        var target = $("#div2");
        var target2 = $("#div3");

            jsPlumb.connect({
                source : source,
                target : target
            });
            jsPlumb.connect({
                source : source,
                target : target2
            });


        });


</script>
<style type="text/css">
#outer{

    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    /*background-color: red;*/

}
.inner{

    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
     margin-bottom: 37px;
}
#div2{
    position: relative; left: 114px; top: -7px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div id="outer">

        <div class="inner" id="div1">
        </div>
        <div class="inner" id="div2">
        </div>
        <div class="inner" id="div3">
        </div>



    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

add jsPlumb library

Answer (score 0):

Configure jsplumb to use static anchors - https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/anchors.html#static